# How to pause the loop after pressing a key?

Tags: c++, loops

I have a loop like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= b; j++) {
        cout << "(" << i << "," << j << ")" << test_resize.at<uchar>(i, j);
    }
}
```

I want to do a pause after cout during the loop if I press a button, for example the space, and return running the loop after another press of the space button. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a part of a GUI framework or something? There is no cross platform way to check if a key is pressed for C++

Comment: As part of your framework, you will have a mechanism (events, for instance) to capture keystrokes and handle them as you desire. That's what you'll need to implement.

Comment: you can do that by breaking the loop, if you want to pause it you need to run your loops in different thread.

Comment: @JoshWeinstein It should be a part of GUI framework, I have included the opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp.

Comment: I would try looking into multi-threading. It may be a bit much for what you are trying to do, but it will get the trick done.